# Error "It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs" when running any `dotnet` command

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows

When running a simple `dotnet --version` on a fresh computer with the Windows Hosting Bundle 3.1 installed, you may get this error message:

```
It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from: https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

what is causing this issue ?

PS: I created this question because all other questions dealing with this error message are within the scope of `docker` or other specific programs and not .NET generally.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you have installed the ASP.NET Core Runtime (<=> Windows Hosting Bundle) but not the .NET Core Runtime itself. The tricky part is that the former still install the `dotnet` command but not the libraries that make it work.

So, contrarily to what may be assumed according to [this](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1/runtime), the Windows Hosting Bundle does **not** install the .NET SDK (at least for v3.1) which has to be installed explicitly too in order to make the `dotnet` command work.

Comment: What about that Microsoft link implies that the runtime installs the SDK?  "runtime" bundles and "sdk" bundles have always been discrete, and the runtime version is basically defined as the minimum subset of the sdk that is required to actually execute application code.

Comment: @KirkWoll This: "The ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle includes the .NET Core Runtime and ASP.NET Core Runtime". This sentence precisely implies that `dotnet` will work by installing the hosting bundle only.

Comment: Apologies, but I am still mystified how you drew that conclusion.  That quote is pretty explicit about dealing with "runtimes" which is a loaded term that explicitly speaks to this entire distinction.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last sentence. I'm not an expert on the topic myself and I agree there may be some confusion between Runtime/SDK on my part. I simply wanted to provide help to people that might get into the same situation in the future and who would only find docker-related answers, and explain that even though Microsoft seems to imply that installing the Windows Hosting Bundle will get us a functional `dotnet` command, it does not and we need to install the SDK manually.

Comment: Hey adamency, totally appreciate your initiative to self-answer your question!  But my question was around why you thought installing the runtime would provide a functional `dotnet` command.  In my experience, I have no expectations that `dotnet` will be functional by merely installing the runtime.  It's _entirely_ possible I've missed something, but that has been the crux of my dialog.

Comment: Also, googling that error message, I agree other answers are highly docker-centric. I think a high quality canonical answer to your specific question would be a great addition to SO.

Comment: Thanks for your message, that's indeed what I was trying to achieve :). Feel free to edit my answer if you have a more precise/clearer explanation. The bottom line of my post is that the windows hosting bundle actually installs the `dotnet` command, but it is unusable without the SDK. More precisely, installing this `dotnet-hosting-3.1.23-win.exe` alone will get you a `dotnet` command, but you also need to install `dotnet-sdk-3.1.417-win-x64.exe` so that it is functional.